# MATLAB - Error while writing output in a CSV file using fprintf

Tags: matlab, printf

I am consistently getting an error while writing output in a CSV file using fprintf. I actually want to write my results in a CSV file. I have tried different lengths of the matrix, and I get the same error even with two columns. What's the mistake here and how can I resolve this error?

Sample code:

```
colname = {'col1' 'col2' 'col3'};
fid = fopen('test.csv','w');
fprintf(fid, '%s, %s, %s\n', colname{1:});
for p=1:5
    % <Some code>
    fname = %reading image name from a directory
    % <Some code>
    val1 = %calculating value1
    val2 = %calculating value2
    datacol = {fname val1 val2};
    fprintf(fid, '%s, %f, %f\n', datacol{p+1:});
end
fclose(fid);
```

Error:

> ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions. at fprintf(fid, '%s, %f, %f\n', datacol{p+1:});

P.S.: Writing "datacol = {fname val1 val2};" as "datacol = {fname,val1,val2};" brought the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

You are indexing the cell contents of datacol.
If I am not mistaken datacol looks sth like this:

```
{'some_string_for_the_name', 1, 2}
```

Where 1 and 2 are val1 and val2.
During your loop you access datacol{p+1} which obviously is datcol{4} for p = 3.
Since your cell only has three elements, indexing a fourth will result in an error. What you probably would like to do is print the lines of val1 and val2, no?
Changing your fprintf to

```
fprintf(fid, '%s, %f, %f\n', datacol{1}, datacol{2}, datacol{3});
```

should solve your problem.